# Increment/Deincrment value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Table:**

[image]

What I am trying to do is ++ or -- the ORD value by selecting the id_phonebook.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE id_phonebook = '$entry_id' ALTER ORD-1
```

Am I going the right way about this or do I need to make this query more sophisticated? Not much of a DB Admin.

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: No you're not. ALTER cannot be used to change data inside. It is used to add delete or modify columns not column data. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp .

Comment: This is not really related to PHP at all...

Comment: @DipenShah Probably just professional rivalry, but see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need an UPDATE statement.

To increment:

```
update phonebook set ord=ord +1 where id_phonebook = '$entry_id'
```

To decrement:

```
update phonebook set ord=ord -1 where id_phonebook = '$entry_id'
```

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html